# Can a person of average intelligence get a PhD in physics or math if he or she works hard enough?

Tags: phd

Or is a PhD a ceiling that they'll never be able to reach, no matter how hard they worked?

By average intelligence I mean a person who has an IQ of 100.

Comment: of course they can

Comment: It might be interesting to repeat the IQ test after doing the PhD. Does several years of practice at problem solving lead to an increased score on a typical  IQ test?

Comment: I don't like this question. On the one hand one could get a definitive answer by giving one positive example, but probably this is not the real question asked here. One the other hand it is pretty clear that "intelligence" is a very vague concept - one may be tempted to answer "got a PhD" is a kind of *definition* for "above average intelligence" (although Pete's answer below indicates that at least the IQ is correlated with academic success). Finally, I do not like the conditioning on "worked hard enough". Hard work is always necessary for a PhD, but never sufficient.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not well posed.

Comment: I voted to close the question because I don't think it's well posed. There are statistics about the IQ of PhD grads. You could ask about that, for example. See https://brainsize.wordpress.com/2014/07/12/the-iqs-of-academic-elites/

Comment: This also supposes that "a PhD" is a uniform standard.  In practice the level of "achievement" needed to earn a PhD, and the specific skills required,  vary greatly across institutions, countries, advisors, subfields, etc.  There may not even be any clear minimum threshold.

Comment: It costs about $200USD to buy a PhD from a diploma mill.  Thus a clear minimum threshold has been established.

Comment: @emory: I'll sell you one for $195!

Comment: are terms like 'smart' or 'IQ' really scientific though? see [NNT](https://medium.com/incerto/iq-is-largely-a-pseudoscientific-swindle-f131c101ba39) aka [Nero](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/88078/), [Dweck](https://news.stanford.edu/pr/2007/pr-dweck-020707.html) and [salman khan](https://www.khanacademy.org/college-careers-more/talks-and-interviews/talks-and-interviews-unit/conversations-with-sal/a/the-learning-myth-why-ill-never-tell-my-son-hes-smart)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I recently reread Malcolm Gladwell's book *Outliers*, which has a discussion of this very point, i.e., IQ versus academic success.  The gist of it is that, like it or not, the IQ test robustly measures something so that a score below X will, with high probability, prevent academic success at level Y.  E.g. a child with an IQ below 50 will have trouble taking classes with other students.  I just checked the passage, and he claims, quoting from Arthur Jensen's book *Bias in Mental Testing*, that with high probability someone with an IQ of below 115 cannot graduate from a university with grades that will get them into graduate school.

One key phrase in the above is **with high probability**.  Thus no one is claiming that such success is impossible, but it becomes significantly more unlikely.  Another important point -- in fact, the whole point of this part of the book -- is that while having an IQ *above the threshold* seems to be important, the importance quickly disappears past the threshold.  In particular, though we may disagree whether the IQ threshold for getting a PhD in mathematics is 100 or 115 or whatever, beyond a certain level *there is no significant correlation between IQ and academic success*.  You might expect someone with an IQ of 175 to have a huge mathematical advantage over someone with an IQ of 125.  But this really seems not to be the case.

Let me say finally that this answer should not in any practical sense be discouraging to anyone.  If you or anyone else is wondering whether you have the intellectual capacity to get a PhD in mathematics -- you don't find out the answer by taking an IQ test, you find out the answer by studying mathematics and doing the best you can.  Someone who has a measured IQ of, say, 95 but gets a degree from a reputable university with excellent grades in challenging courses and competitive test scores: of course such a student should seriously consider getting a PhD in mathematics if they are interested, and should not be dissuaded at all by their "low IQ".

Comment: +1 for the only answer that actually addresses the question and uses references instead of first-principles reasoning to do so.

Comment: Nice answer, but given that probably most of the academics around the world do not take an IQ test, I wonder how much the research of the book is reliable, and whether the author considered both STEM fields and the humanities.

Comment: I wouldn't put much faith in anything Gladwell writes.  He's smart but very lazy and tends to do a lot of cherry-picking to back his premises.

Comment: @Carl: In this particular case, Gladwell is directly quoting from a book that I identified.  If you look it up, you will see that this is a serious academic work that has been subjected to an immense amount of scrutiny.  Which of course is not to say that one should simply accept its conclusions -- many academics have been critical of the work -- but simply brushing it aside doesn't do justice to the academic process.

Comment: Just as the relationship between IQ and academic success is complicated, the relationship between academic success and any other kind of success is complicated.  Even assuming a certain individual was unlikely to succeed in a PhD program, the same individual might make an outstanding President of the United States.

Comment: I'd tend to echo @CarlWitthoft's hesitancy about M. Gladwell as reliable source: yes, he does tend to "cite" things, but in a fashion that amounts to choosing hypotheses _after_ a statistical test has been run, rather than doing an honest test of one's pet hypothesis against The Null Hypothesis. Obvious conflict of interest interpretation, too, in the MG "needs" to come up with stuff to sell books... and concluding that things work the way you'd always thought may not do that selling so well.

Comment: @paul: I agree broadly with what you and Carl are saying.  I read Gladwell for entertainment first.  If something seems worth "using," I certainly check for it elsewhere.

Answer (score 5):

Brains (IQ level) may get you into post-grad study but character (perseverance etc) is, by far, more significant in graduating...   as a PhD will require personal qualities that IQ does not measure...

With fewer formal assessments and milestones than an undergraduate degree there is a greater requirement for these characteristics.   Things that I found important were persistence, imagination, literacy, time management, able to take criticism and respond appropriately and so many more.

As there are many bright people on the planet who did not have the interest or opportunity to study at university level, people for whom a PhD would be readily achievable it is unwise to make arbitrary decisions based on a couple of IQ points.  Consider emotional intelligence and various other measures of human characteristics as well e.g. Autism Spectrum conditions

Comment: This seems like an answer to the question "Is a high IQ sufficient for a successful PhD" - but that's not the question that was asked.  The question asks whether a high IQ is _necessary_, not whether it is _sufficient_.

Comment: I noted that many people capable of PhD level work do not graduate so just a high IQ is insufficient.  I am aware of one field where "below average intelligence" is IQ < 70, presumably "average" is 70-130?  Arbitrary limits e.g. if IQ<130 then PhD = nil may be difficult to enforce.  Until peer-reviewed evidence shows an arbitrary IQ level is the *sole* arbiter of academic success, my experience is that personal characteristics are a big influence on academic success.  Additionally, PhD selection is competitive and relies on assessed undergraduate work with course average being important.

Comment: I agree that perseverance is far more important for the kind of people who are admitted to grad school -- people who got good grades in undergrad, get good letters of recommendation and have decent GRE scores. But that is already filtering the pool for something like high IQ. It doesn't follow that someone who had none of these features would do well, regardless of how persistent they were.

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to get a PhD with an IQ of 100, but not impossible.

There are several ramifications of "IQ." One possibility is that someone of an average (100) IQ will take longer to master a subject than someone with a 115-120 IQ or that the lower IQ person will need to repeat some courses. If such a person "gets it" eventually, that person will need to work longer and harder than some others, but can achieve the PhD eventually. This is known as the [speed versus power](http://www.psychometric-success.com/aptitude-tests/speed-versus-power-tests.htm) dichotomy.

In another instance, the lower IQ might refer to a "cap" in the level of someone's intellectual ability. That is harder to deal with than the situation in the previous paragraph, and more planning is required. For instance, someone with a 100 IQ who is good in mechanics might be a poor candidate to study atomic physics, but his/her knowledge of everyday mechanics might make it possible to get a PhD in "lower level" physics.

As the New York Times [reported](http://www.nytimes.com/2016/09/18/opinion/sunday/the-difference-between-rationality-and-intelligence.html?_r=0), psychologists Daniel Kahneman and Amos Tversky have found a distinct difference between "intelligence," and "rationality" (both of which are important in physics). Thus, a person of average "intelligence" might be highly rational, which is enough compensation, at least for the more mechanical, less theoretical part of physics.

In fact, a person with a high IQ that lacked other essential qualities such as rationality/logic, diligence, and tenacity might have a harder time getting a PhD, at least in physics, than some others.

Comment: Are these supposed consequences of IQ actually supported by evidence?

Comment: @Tom Au is saying that there are various branches in physics, with alot of room for almost everyone. For example, mathematical/theoretical physics might be harder to understand than numerical simulations(many body physics), or experimental/data analysis. Most of my peers who have done very poorly in courses like quantum mechanics or advanced quantum mechanics, electrodynamics, are about to finish a PhD in experimental physics with a lot of group publications, even first author papers.

Comment: @NateEldredge: I added two links to support my hypotheses. Is the post better now?

Comment: are terms like 'smart' or 'IQ' really scientific though? see [NNT](https://medium.com/incerto/iq-is-largely-a-pseudoscientific-swindle-f131c101ba39) aka [Nero](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/88078/), [Dweck](https://news.stanford.edu/pr/2007/pr-dweck-020707.html) and [salman khan](https://www.khanacademy.org/college-careers-more/talks-and-interviews/talks-and-interviews-unit/conversations-with-sal/a/the-learning-myth-why-ill-never-tell-my-son-hes-smart)

Comment: The "speed vs power" link is really bull.... Unrelated to this subject.

Answer (score 2):

While the question has some merit, I still think it is ultimately the wrong question because it puts too much stress on number evaluation.

Choosing a subject for study is mostly not for pure interest, but to choose what you want to do in your professional life afterwards (Another thing is if you really get to work in this specific job, but *noone*, *really noone* I talked to repented studying his favorite subject).

So if you have a keen interest in physics and/or math, the best thing to do is trying it out. If you are not qualified, you *will* soon see reason because you seem to be incarcerated in inscrutable reasoning. The thing is if you are qualified, you will have precious light-bulb moments, their frequency increasing with your ability.

Feynman, the Nobel Prize winner, gloatingly declined the invitation to Mensa, the intelligentsia club, because he had only a 125 score. And many, many experimental physicists are struggling with math requirements, but are
shining in their necessary strengths of meticulousness and perserverance. Intelligence is an umbrella term for many kinds of thinking, so yes, you may have weaknesses, but also strengths and if those strengths allow you to study math and physics, do it (While I have now decades of English experience, languages are not loving me and vice versa).

**So the answer is: Yes, if you have the necessary other talents, even average intelligence will allow you to get an PhD**.

I suspect there are other reasons why you are asking, especially because you asked for the PhD, not studying itself. The problem is that many people, *especially parents*, simply do not understand or do not want to understand that **success in math and physics cannot be achieved by sheer willpower and perserverance**. If you do not have the talent (intelligence one core talent, but not the ultimate deciding factor), pursuing math and physics is wasting lifetime. To make progress, you must (!) understand the concepts involved because they are the fundamental basis for the next steps, see how they are interact with each other and get a "feeling"/"view" for the situation. This is the basis for the next step and so on and so on. Rote memorization is useless.

On the other hand, if you have the talent, both willpower and perserverance are godsends and it is unlikely that you will succeed to get an PhD if you do not have those qualities.

The often-heard Edison phrase in this context *"Genius is one percent inspiration and ninety-nine percent perspiration."* is a severe misconception because it is highly dubious that Edison ever personally worked on or invented himself something. He simply had his payed workers and took credit for the things other people developed. Innovator, not inventor.

Comment: "[B]ecause it is highly dubious that Edison ever personally worked on or invented himself something." You are making a contention that differs from all the biographical and historical material I have seen.  See e.g. http://edison.rutgers.edu/biogrphy.htm which describes how Edison spent his early years as an "independent inventor", including several years without any assistants of any kind.  Since presumably you do not have personal knowledge of these events that took place more than 100 years ago, I wonder if you could identify the source material that led you to this dissenting opinion.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark This will be a longer story, so if you are really interested I suggest we are meeting in chat so I can show how I come to this dissenting opinion.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark Hint: The link you give strangely fails to mention the time from 1869 where he worked together with Franklin Leonard Pope and that part of life was erased in the chronology of Rutgers. From 1871 on (Newark) he always worked with a team, there were no "early years". Most "inventions" claimed by Edison were perfecting already existing designs and neither Pope nor Tesla hold him in high regard as inventor. And foremost, I did not find any instance where *Edison actually claimed that he personally invented the things ascribed to him*.